# Is it possible to return the missing value of a WHERE IN query

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I want to do some data validation. I have a sender_id and a receiver_id. I want to validate that each id I'm receiving is valid. I'm trying to avoid looping over the returned query and the list I'm comparing.

I have a users table with a primary id column, name, etc.

When a message is sent I was to grab the sender and receiver ids, make them into an array, and then query the DB as follows:

```
SELECT id FROM users WHERE id IN (1, 999);
```

In my test case, I know that `id 999` doesn't exist.

What I'd like to do is make the IN query (or the query that makes this possible) and have it return `999` rather than `1` - or nothing if both exist. Is this possible?

Comment: Could you clarify what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: If I make the query `SELECT id FROM users WHERE id IN (1, 999);` and the only record that exists is somebody with the ID 1, it will return the row where ID is 1. What I would like is for it to return `999` which is the ID that doesn't exist (it wouldn't return a row because there is no row. I can't use NOT EXIST, because I get all of the rows not equal to `1` or `999`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a `VALUES` clause instead:

```
select *
from (values(1),(999)) my_ids(my_id)
where my_id not in (select id from users)
order by my_id;
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_8.4&fiddle=e0d88e36be9c42addf6a0c6357558bf7

Comment: I'll read into value more and get a better understanding. But this does the trick.

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
select 999
from users
where id = 1;
```

This will return 999 if user exists. If not, there will be no result.